# How to debug in VSCode

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem with the Golang debugger in Visual Studio Code.
My launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 2345,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "env": {},
        "args": []
    }
]
```

I put a breakpoint, I launch the debugger, it start up and write to the Debug Console:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:2345
```

and nothing else happens!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: GoLand JetBrains too not work debugging

Comment: most likely problem in WSL

Comment: Are you waiting the necessary time? First time you run it it may take some minutes to have a response.

Comment: Any feedback @iGaisin?

Comment: @joao-henrique I waited a lot of time, about while the movie was going